# localization and ideals

Tags: ring-theory

Statement: Every ideal J in S$^-$$^1$R is of the form S$^-$$^1$I for some ideal I in R.

Proof:

Let J = (j$_\alpha$: $\alpha$ $\in$ A) Then j$_\alpha$ = h(r$_\alpha$)h(s$_\alpha$)$^-$$^1$. Define I to be the ideal in R generated by {r$_\alpha$: $\alpha$ $\in$ A}; that is I = h$^-$$^1$(h(R)$\cap$J)

I am trying to show this last equality, I $\subseteq$ h$^-$$^1$(h(R)$\cap$J to be specific.

Suppose i $\in$ h$^-$$^1$(h(R)$\cap$J) then h(i) = h(r) = h(r')h(s')$^-$$^1$h(j$_\alpha$) for some r in R. Hence xis'=xr'j$_\alpha$ for some x in S. How do I show that i is in I at last? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think your question would be a lot easier to read if you used mathmode for every equation (and other maths) - i.e. write $J = (j_\alpha : \alpha \in A)$ instead of J = (j$_\alpha$:$\alpha \in$ A). That's how most people format their maths, and this is a bit jarring in contrast.

Comment: Thx for the suggestion!

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your $I$ is actually not well-defined, and also not necessarily an ideal. Consider $R = \mathbb{Z}_{12}$, and $S = \{9\}$. Then $S$ is multiplicatively closed since $9^2 =9 \in S$, so we may safely localise at $S$. Now, let $J \subseteq S^{-1}R$ be the ideal $J = \{0\}$.

If we define
$$
A = \{\alpha_0\},\quad r_{\alpha_0} = 4, \quad s_{\alpha_0} = 1
$$
and $j_{\alpha_0} = \frac{r_{\alpha_0}}{s_{\alpha_0}}$, then $j_{\alpha_0} = \frac{4}{1} = 0$ in $S^{-1}R$, so using your terminology,
$$
J = \Big\{\frac{r_{\alpha}}{s_{\alpha}} : \alpha \in A\Big\}
$$
However, by your definition $I = \{r_{\alpha_0}\} = \{4\}$. If we had instead chosen $r_{\alpha_0} = 0$, then we would instead have obtained $I = \{0\}$. Clearly then $I$ is not well-defined by $J$, and also it is not necessarily an ideal (since in the first case it is not, but in the second case it is). Since $I$ is not well-defined, and $h^{-1}(h(R)\cap J)$ is, we cannot hope for them to be equal.

So how can we fix this? Get rid of the indexing by $\alpha$, and just define
$$
I = \Big\{r : \frac{r}{s} \in J\Big\} = \Big\{r:\exists s\in R\text{ such that } \frac{r}{s}\in J\Big\}
$$
where the left-hand definition is an informal version of the right-hand one, but they are the same.

Can you make your argument from this definition? The direction you were struggling with before now follows almost immediately.

I'd also note that you can drop the $h(R)$ from your expression for $I$, and just write $I = h^{-1}(J)$ instead. This is basically because every element of $R$ is in the preimage of $h(R)$. Showing fully that $h^{-1}(h(R) \cap J) = h^{-1}(J)$ takes a couple of lines of writing, and if it's not immediately obvious, it might be a good exercise.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for this much writing! This is actually Corollary 4.74 from Rotman's Introduction to Homological Algebra. And S there is defined to include 1. Would this make a difference? Thx again!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm hesitant to contradict Rotman, but I think his use of the indexing set $\Lambda$ is somewhat ambiguous. I guess he means that he is indexing every pair $(r, s) \in R^2$ with $r/s \in J$, but without that caveat it does seem to cause problems. I'm pretty sure my example still works with $S = \{1, 9\}$, so I don't think the $1$ makes a difference.

Comment: I also note that he uses $h^{-1}(h(R) \cap J)$, which seriously diminishes my confidence in the last paragraph of my answer. I guess maybe he includes $h(R)$ because $h$ can be considered as a map $R \to h(R)$, but his own definition gives $S^{-1}R$ as the codomain, so I'm not sure why he's done that.

Comment: thank you anyway for digging into this! Appreciate your time!